# Globals across Angular services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Can I define global variables or functions that can be accessed by all of my Angular service modules?

For example, I have several services that make http requests to various endpoints of the same url root. I would like to be able to change this root.

My service modules look like this.

```
var host = 'http://my-api.com'; 
return {
get: function(id) {
    return $http({
        url: host + '/contacts/' + id,
        method: 'GET'
      });
},
...
switchHost: function(url){
    host = url;
}
});
```

So I can call `ContactService.switchHost('http://new-url')` in my Controllers to update this particular Service.

I would like to have some sort of *Root Service* where I coul define `host` and `switchHost` globally.

Note: The use case here is that some of our clients will be accessing our company API, and others will be self-hosting their resources.

Comment: What is preventing you to write this Root Service? Seems like a great idea. :)

Comment: You could also use an http interceptor, which will read the baseurl from a config and append it to the relative url..

Comment: Angular allows you to register [constant services](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) (similar to your _Root Service_).

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to create an interceptor which will digest an angular value like this.

```
angular.module('...')
.value('HOST', 'http://www.fu.bar.com/')
.factory('InterceptorFactory', function (HOST) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {

            config.url = HOST + config.url;

            return config;
        }
    };
})
.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {


    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('InterceptorFactory');
}]);
```

Whenever you call the $http service, the factory will be called and will add your host.
If you want to update the host, you just need to inject in any block the value and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I just did something like this.

```
angular.module('app.services').factory('RootService', function($http) {
    return {
        switchHost: function(url){
            this.host = url;
        },
        host: 'http://app.apiary-mock.com'
    }
});
```

This way the client can just type in a url on the settings page and the root will change, which is what I want.