# Set a global database service in Angular 4, is it possible?

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to somehow set a global angular service which will work within my whole Angular 4 app? I have a firebase database set up in one component and a module, is it possible to use it in another component without declaring everything once again? I've tried to make an interceptor - is it a good approach (based on this: [Globals across Angular services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366366/globals-across-angular-services)) or maybe there is some Firebase support for this issue?

Comment: Sure, make a service, provide it in `AppModule´ and inject it whereever you want to use it. That's all.

Comment: Usually, I use several singleton services in my application. So I create a `CoreModule` imported in the `AppModule`, and the `CoreModule` will only provide my global application services (such as your firebase database service)

Comment: Could you please give an example of this? I've tried to make it like described [here](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/61/Angular-4-Services-Tutorial), but it still doesn't work and shows no errors both in a Chrome console and a terminal.